# Does Chatter Answers come with Salesforce Knowledge?

Tags: chatter, customer-portal, community

We are a non-profit and got a quote on salesforce knowledge but does anyone know if that includes access to chatter answers?

Do portal users who access chatter answers have to pay extra for that?

Also related to that, how will chatter answers work with the upcoming chatter communities?  will we be able to use both?

Comment: The Salesforce Communities pricing (and pricing model) hasn't be announced yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chatter Answers is a $0 cost add-on with Portal licenses, so the answer to your first question is 'No, portal users who access chatter answers will not have to pay extra for that'.

As [Ryan Guest](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/23/ryan-guest) [says in a comment above](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8331/does-chatter-answers-come-with-salesforce-knowledge/8337#comment11828_8331), there is no public info yet on Chatter Answers as it relates to Communities.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a separate Chatter Answers feature license, and won't be part of the knowledge feature license.  I'd imagine this is a paid license, but I haven't seen the pricing, nor could I find it through google, so this is one to ask your Account Executive about.

Chatter communities is still in pilot and I haven't been able to get access so anything I said about that would be pure guesswork!